# ruby: How to get the first hash item from an array if some keys of items are the same?

Tags: ruby, arrays, hash

For example:

```
array = [
  {"a"=>1, "b"=>2, "c"=>3},
  {"a"=>1, "b"=>2, "c"=>4},
  {"a"=>2, "b"=>1, "c"=>5},
  {"a"=>2, "b"=>1, "c"=>6}
]
```

If key `a` and key `b` are both the same in the hash, I want to get the first item. Such as:

```
array = [
  {"a"=>1, "b"=>2, "c"=>3},
  {"a"=>2, "b"=>1, "c"=>5}
]
```

Is there any way to distinct the hash key and get the first one?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use [Array#uniq](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.3/Array.html#method-i-uniq), with a block

```
array.uniq {|h| [h['a'],h['b']] }
# => [{"a"=>1, "b"=>2, "c"=>3}, {"a"=>2, "b"=>1, "c"=>5}]
```

Comment: +1 Much better than mine. However it should be `[h['a'],h['b']]`

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following:

```
arr=[]
array.each do|h|
 arr.push h if !arr.any?{|hash|hash["a"]==h["a"] && hash["b"]==h["b"]} 
end
p arr
```